# Jboss AS7 - jboss-deployment-structure.xml deployment error

Tags: jboss7.x

When I add the jboss-deployment-structure.xml in to my .war and deploy in the AS7 giving the following error.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2}jboss-deployment-structure'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
```

Sample xml is attached below.

```
    <jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Is there any reason why I get the deployment error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's complaining that you haven't specified the namespace. I updated the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) for excluding log4j to add the namespace.

Try this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Be careful, **urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2** is not available with JBoss AS 7.1.1. For this version of JBoss use **jboss:deployment-structure:1.1** (see [comment](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7?focusedCommentId=53379592#comment-53379592))

Comment: And **deployment-structure:1.2** is available starting from JBoss AS 7.1.2 / EAP 6.x : see source [xsd](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/blob/7.1.2.Final/build/src/main/resources/docs/schema/jboss-deployment-structure-1_2.xsd)