# javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1] (jboss-deployment-structure.xml)

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, jboss7.x, java-ee-7

I want my application to use the **Validation-api-1.1.0.Final** jar instead of the container provided jar **Validation-api-1.0.0.GA** which comes with JBoss-AS-7.1.1. I created the JBoss **jboss-deployment-structure.xml** as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.validation.api" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But I keep getting this exception below:

```
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Error loading jboss-structure.xml from C:\MissionControlPkg\JBoss Server\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp7f73eea962903738\content-4b7503af3f3c7a91\WEB-INF\jboss-deployment-structure.xml
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:277) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:249) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.deploy(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:134) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2}jboss-deployment-structure'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:271) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 8 more
```

I have looked at this question [Jboss AS7 - jboss-deployment-structure.xml deployment error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995263/jboss-as7-jboss-deployment-structure-xml-deployment-error)
and this https://community.jboss.org/message/717927#717927